# Substring search is failing...Any ideas?

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

I am trying to find the occurrence of a substring in an array.
Here is the string:

```
$string = "Watch the game at @TheGoalTX on #GoaltimeSaturdays!"
```

Here is the array:

```
$venues = array (
    [ "name" => "McDonalds", "slogan" => "Im Lovin It" ],
    [ "name" => "The Goal", "slogan" => "GoaltimeSaturday" ],
    [ "name" => "McDonalds", "slogan" => "McRibs are back" ],
    );
```

Im running an array search in which I want to run a script if either search condition is true:

```
foreach ($venues as $venue) {
    if ((stristr($string,$venue['name'])) OR (stristr($string,$venue['slogan'])) !== false) {
        include "do.stuff.php";
        }
    }
```

The two array rows with McDonalds obviously fails. No problem.

But for some reason, the search is failing for the "slogan" element "GoaltimeSaturday" and Im not quite sure why. It should meet the "if" criteria but "do.stuff.php" is never reached.

A little help here / any ideas? Are the """ emotes or the "#" or "@" characters in the string the issue perhaps? Im at a loss as to why Im not getting a true/positive search result in the foreach loop...

I appreciate the assistance on this...

Comment: I tested with a simple echo inside the if and it worked, so may be something with the file you included.

Comment: it's working fine at my end, there's nothing wrong. Try checking the included file for any issue.

Comment: That appears to be the case. Thanks @GarrGodfrey and OMi

Answer (score -1):

If  `include "do.stuff.php"` never reached, but you await for reaching it, it means your condition is incorrect.
I think the problem is extra braces, try this:

```
if ((stristr($string,$venue['name']) OR stristr($string,$venue['slogan'])) !== false)
```

Also i don't know about difference between OR logic operators 'OR' or '||'.

**UPD**

1. May you show `do.stuff.php` file content?
2. Is there are any errors or notices in logs or console output?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with the code. It has to definitely do with the included file.

Comment: It was the braces. Thanks!